# How to Google search videos from websites other than YouTube?

Tags: google-search

I want to Google search for videos on "JavaScript". However, I want search results from websites other than YouTube. How can I do that?

Since I want video results, I selected the Videos tab on the Google search results page. But how to ***exclude*** YouTube results? The [operators page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?visit_id=0-636196579457576248-2844417274&p=adv_operators&hl=en&rd=1) doesn't offer any suggestions to this effect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [page you're linking to](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?visit_id=0-636196579457576248-2844417274&p=adv_operators&hl=en&rd=1) *does* describe how to do that:

> When you use a dash before a word or site, it excludes sites with that
>   info from your results. This is useful for words with multiple
>   meanings, like Jaguar the car brand and jaguar the animal. Examples:
>   `jaguar speed -car or pandas -site:wikipedia.org`

[Do a video search for `javascript -site:youtube.com`](https://www.google.no/search?q=javascript%20-site:youtube.com&tbm=vid) to exclude results from youtube.com.

Note the dash: If you [searched for `javascript site:youtube.com`](https://www.google.no/search?q=javascript%20site:youtube.com&tbm=vid) you would restrict results to *only* videos from youtube.com. From the same documentation page:

> `site:` Get results from certain sites or domains. Example:
>   `olympics site:nbc.com`
>   To get results from multiple sites or domains,
>   combine with OR. Example: `Olympics site:nbc.com OR site:.gov`